# NullPointerException in constructor

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception, actionlistener

I have narrowed down my problem to one line of Java code in my GUI.

```
Shop1.addProduct(new Product(proid, proName, proPrice, proQis));
```

Each time I click the button that I've attached it to. It isn't the button as that runs fine without it.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ShopFrame$AddListener.actionPerformed(ShopFrame.java:56)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can't for the life of me figure out the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `Shop1` is `null`. Try adding a null-check:

```
if(Shop1 != null) Shop1.addProduct(new Product(proid, proName, proPrice, proQis));
```

Also, as an aside note, follow Java naming conventions and don't start your variables with capital letters. Instead of `Shop1`, use `shop1`.

Comment: If you do something special in `new Product(proid, proName, proPrice, proQis)` constructor, the variables `proid`, `proName`, `proPrice`, `proQis` can be null, as well, They can cause the same NPE.

Comment: @GaborSch +1 I agree, but in most cases, constructors are used only for assigning instance fields. Specially, for Java bean-like classes (i.e `Product`).

Comment: Yes, I agree, but there is a (very) small chance for that anyway, and we don't see the internals of the constructor.

Comment: It seems to me that it is to do with trying to access methods of Shop class as I go the same error again when I tried to call another one.

Comment: is Shop1 a class, or an instance?

Comment: It is an instance of the class Shop.